# Spring state machine gui

Tags: java, modeling, spring-statemachine

Is there any customer-facing GUI interface for configuring Spring state machine flows. Papyrus is complicated to install and use. Need something more simple, however, somehow support integration with Spring to visually run and debug the state machine model.

thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Jim,  I'm searching for a library/framework allowing to visually define and debug state machine flows.  As a state machine engine, I will be using spring state machine library.  It can work with Papyrus tool as a UI framework for definition and debugging. I managed to define and configure the tool, however, it is very complicated for the end user to use.  I searching for an open source alternative targeting non-programmers, so any suggestion (even opinionated) based on experience will help.